# Problem with variable for if statement in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hy everyone, i've a problem with my script, because when i launch it for testing and press the L0 button i receive this error message:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "nucleo.py", line 33, in spegni
>       value = int(previous_state.get())                                         UnboundLocalError: local variable 'previous_state' referenced before assignment

I show my full code:

```
import serial

import random

import time

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

import os

previuos_state=0

def accendi():
  if previous_state == 0:
    TimeDelay = random.randrange(10,20)
    time.sleep(TimeDelay)

    ser.write('L1'.encode())

    previous_state = 1

    USER_TIME = list(ser.read(5).decode("utf8"))

    if USER_TIME[0] == 'T':


        USER_TIME = str(USER_TIME[1])+str(USER_TIME[2])+str(USER_TIME[3])+str(USER_TIME[4])

        print(str(int(USER_TIME,16))+" ms")

    else:

        print("Errore in ricezione")
  else:
    messagebox.showwarning("Attenzione", "Spegnere led per iniziare un nuovo test")
def spegni():

  if previous_state == 1:
    TimeDelay = random.randrange(10,20)
    time.sleep(TimeDelay)

    ser.write('L0'.encode())

    previous_state = 0

    USER_TIME = list(ser.read(5).decode("utf8"))

    if USER_TIME[0] == 'T':

        USER_TIME = str(USER_TIME[1])+str(USER_TIME[2])+str(USER_TIME[3])+str(USER_TIME[4])

        print(str(int(USER_TIME,16))+" ms")


    else:

        print("Errore in ricezione")

else:
    messagebox.showwarning("Attenzione", "Accendere led per iniziare un nuovo test")


finestra=Tk()
finestra.geometry("520x230")
finestra.title("Misuratore di riflessi")
testo=Label(finestra, text="Premere il pulsante L0 se il LED è acceso\nPremere il pulsante L1 se il LED è spento\nPremere  EXIT per uscire")
testo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
tasto1=Button(finestra, text="L0", command=spegni)
tasto1.grid(row=3, column=0)
tasto2=Button(finestra, text="L1", command=accendi)
tasto2.grid(row=3, column=2)
lista=Listbox(finestra)
lista.insert(END, "uno", "due", "tre", "quattro", "cinque", "sei", "sette", "otto")
lista.grid(row=0, column= 3, columnspan=5, rowspan=5)
tasto3=Button(finestra, text="EXIT", command=exit)
tasto3.grid(row=4, column=1)

finestra.mainloop()
```

I don't understand why i can't use the variable "previuous_state", in the functions.

Comment: You haven't posted the code that contains the error (i.e. `value = int(previous_state.get())`)

Answer (score 0):

previous state is misspelled in its initial declaration

```
import serial

import random

import time

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

import os

previuos_state=0
```

This makes your checks at the start of your functions fail as the variable is not declared

Comment: sorry but i don't understand, because i watch the cose a lot of time and i can't see a misspelled problem, infact i create also a button for print the variable and when i press it i see that the variable was correctly assigned to 0. But when i enter in the function "spegni" the variable disappear. If you want i can post also che code with the "print button".

Comment: The last line `previuos_state=0` should be `previous_state=0` , your o and u are in the wrong order . If they are not supposed to be the same variable then the names are not unique enough.

Comment: Ok, i committed an error during the copy because i change the code a lot of time, under this message i put the original code and the error remain the same also if the variable have the same name. Do you know why? (i repost the right code as a answer, sorry but i am new)

Comment: Your variable `previous_state` is out of [scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) in the functions it is called in. Using global's is generally a bad idea as it allows variables to be overwritten when it is not appropriate to do so.  changing it to uppercase will make it a  constant and that should resolve it. You should read this and follow it https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ it will help avoid future mistakes .

Answer (score -1):

The right code:

```
import serial
import random
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

previous_state=0

def stampa():
  print(previous_state)

def accendi():
  if previous_state == 0:
    TimeDelay = random.randrange(10,20)
    time.sleep(TimeDelay)

    ser.write('L1'.encode())

    previous_state = 1

    USER_TIME = list(ser.read(5).decode("utf8"))

    if USER_TIME[0] == 'T':


        USER_TIME = str(USER_TIME[1])+str(USER_TIME[2])+str(USER_TIME[3])+str(USER_TIME[4])

        print(str(int(USER_TIME,16))+" ms")

    else:

        print("Errore in ricezione")
   else:
    messagebox.showwarning("Attenzione", "Spegnere led per iniziare un nuovo test")

def spegni():
  if previous_state == 1:
    TimeDelay = random.randrange(10,20)
    time.sleep(TimeDelay)

    ser.write('L0'.encode())

    previous_state = 0

    USER_TIME = list(ser.read(5).decode("utf8"))

    if USER_TIME[0] == 'T':

        USER_TIME = str(USER_TIME[1])+str(USER_TIME[2])+str(USER_TIME[3])+str(USER_TIME[4])

        print(str(int(USER_TIME,16))+" ms")


    else:

        print("Errore in ricezione")

  else:
    messagebox.showwarning("Attenzione", "Accendere led per iniziare un nuovo test")


finestra=Tk()
finestra.geometry("520x230")
finestra.title("Misuratore di riflessi")
testo=Label(finestra, text="Premere il pulsante L0 se il LED è acceso\nPremere il pulsante L1 se il LED è spento\nPremere  EXIT per uscire")
testo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
tasto1=Button(finestra, text="L0", command=spegni)
tasto1.grid(row=3, column=0)
tasto2=Button(finestra, text="L1", command=accendi)
tasto2.grid(row=3, column=2)
lista=Listbox(finestra)
lista.insert(END, "uno", "due", "tre", "quattro", "cinque", "sei", "sette", "otto")
lista.grid(row=0, column= 3, columnspan=5, rowspan=5)     
tasto3=Button(finestra, text="EXIT", command=exit)
tasto3.grid(row=4, column=1)
tastoo=Button(finestra, text="STAMPA", command=stampa)
tastoo.grid(row=1, column=1)

finestra.mainloop()
```

I continue to try but i can't use the variable for the if